# Параллакс на реакт

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend

я сейчас делаю простенький сайт на реакт, и вот у меня, как у новичка возникла такая проблема. Я хотел сделать параллакс, допустим у меня есть горы, за ними еще горы и небо. Когда мышка двигается влево, то ближайшие горы двигаются быстрее, задние медленнее, а небо вообще почти стоит. И в принципе посмотрев видео ролик, я примерно понял как делать на js(рис. 1). Но на реакте, насколько я понимаю нельзя искать элемент (ну или хотя бы не нужно) через DOM дерево, тем самым я не могу поменять стили этому элементу. Обычно я меняю стили на реакте вот так (рис. 2). Но тут у меня проблема, так как при каждом перемещение мышки translate должен менять значение, а если использовать такой метод, то получается я могу сделать translate только фиксированный. На данный момент я сделал такой параллакс(рис 3,4), то есть разделил экран на две части, если мышка слева, то он сдвинулся один раз влево, а если справа, то один раз вправо(мне это решение не очень нравится, поэтому если я очень плохо сделал не оскорбляйте, а просто поправьте и подскажите). Ну так вот, а я хочу не чтобы как у меня один раз влево, а чем мышка дальше, тем он медленнее двигается. Вот пример такого параллакса(на демо нажмите) https://yootheme.com/blog/2014/03/02/frequency-theme. Я мог бы оставить все как есть, но хочу разобраться. Заранее спасибо за понимание и помощь. [image][image][image][image]
[5 вложений]

Comment: Поменьше кода, побольше текста бы. И можно выложит пример ваш либо прямо тут как сниппет, либо на https://codesandbox.io/ либо на https://jsfiddle.net/

Так будет проще разобраться :)

Answer (score 0):

Примерные стили которые ты должен использовать

```
position: relative;
display: block;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
left: 0px; 
top: 0px; 
transform: translate3d(x, y, z); 
transform-style: preserve-3d; 
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Вместо (x,y,z) создай переменные и управляй от курсора.
Согласен с  @Dimabytes
что если ты выложишь фрагмент кода на один из сервисов будет на много проще разобраться и помочь тебе.